# Does it sound OK to say: 'Let's have a quick check of this structure (of a sentence)'?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Does it sound OK to say: 'Let's have a quick check of this structure (of a sentence)' in the meaning let's have a quick look at this structure.

Comment: To me "check" suggests something more than just a look.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something like "Let's quickly check this structure." If you prefer the original, I would substitute the word "do" for "have."